# Material UI dropdown (select) element not updating in onChange in dynamic form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, material-ui

I'm creating a dynamic form that loads some extra fields via some json. My problem is that the  and  elements are not re-rendering after the value is changed. My form is currently a functional component. How do I create hooks on the fly (with useState) so when onChange is triggered these fields update and re-render correctly.

I'm storing the updated values in a dictionary and on submitting I can see the values have been updated. The weird thing is I use exactly the same process using  elements and these re-render okay. Are these uncontrolled somehow? Can I update the  elements outside of using useState?

I tried having a dictionary variable initialised as an empty dictionary using useState but can I add keys and values to this and trigger re-rendering?

Please see my code at https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-mendel-q51ld

**Edit:**

It doesn't seem to be linked to the React hooks (I tried using ones instantiated when the component is first used). I think the issue lies with the `<Select>` and `<Radio>` elements. If they're created programmatically after the component is first rendered then they don't update even when the state variables linked to them update. `<Text>` elements update fine and they are updated by the same mechanism.

I guess a workaround is to create all possible form elements before the first render and then show/hide them as needed but I'd prefer not to do this.

**Update:**

It's definitely an issue with both the `<Select>` and `<Radio>` elements as normal HTML dropdowns and radios update fine.

Comment: [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing your problem would help.

Comment: Sorry, even the minimal code is large. I'll edit the question to add

Comment: The `loadExtraFields()` function is the one that loads the new form fields and the values of the <Text> elements update okay (ie re-render) but he <Radio> and <Select> don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you trigger re-render each time when invoking `setState` which cause uncontrolled state of state :) You need to replace `useState` with [useReducer](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer). In this way you will be able to update whole buch of properties in one re-render. 
To use `useReducer` you need to write reducer before.

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'YOUR_ACTION_TYPE':
    return {
      ...state,
      extraCarFields: false,
      extraOtherFields: true,
      extraOtherFieldsData: action.extraFields
      finalCategory: value
    };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}
```

After that inititalize it

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
```

Then for example instead of

```
setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, extraCarFields: false }))
setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, extraOtherFields: true }))
setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, extraOtherFieldsData: loadExtraFields(otherFields) }))
setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, finalCategory: value }))
```

You will do

```
const extraFields = loadExtraFields(otherFields);
dispatch({ type: "YOUR_ACTION_TYPE", extraFields: extraFields });
```

Also I recommend to read about all available standard [hooks](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html). I think you probably gonna use `useCallback` to memoize your functions and not trigger to initialize them every render. And second recommendation is move to [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) to accomplish correct behaviour when loading ExtraFields before dispatching update to state.

**UPDATE**

To update values in form I use such pattern:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_FIELD":
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.prop]: action.value
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

...

const handleChange = prop => e => {
  const { value } = e.target;
  dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_FIELD", prop: prop, value: value });
};

...

<TextField
      label="Your email address"
      name="email"
      type="email"
      value={state.email}
      onChange={handleChange('email')}
      required autoFocus fullWidth />
```

So you just pass name of your property to `handleChange` function and json magic will do the rest :) Feel free to ask additional questions if I missed something.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I'll try your approach. Do you have any idea why `<Text>` elements update okay but `<Select>` doesn't with my original way of doing stuff?

Comment: @clg123 it's not something with `<Text>` or `<Select>`, you create components in loadExtraFields but after that you never updating their state. You see updates in `<TextField>` beacuse it's just input under the hood and you don't need state update to see what you type there.

Comment: One more question; do I need a different case for each element? In my current onChange function - I pass in event and get the name and value to be updated. In this case how would I update the itemname field? I've tried calling `dispatch({ type: "YOUR_ACTION_TYPE", name: value });` but this doesn't update the field on the form (which is set to `{state.itemname}`. Using your code I can preload the value and have it displayed but I'm unsure exactly how to update. Apologies, I'm used to coding in Perl and Python and am having trouble getting my head round the React way of doing things :)

Comment: or do I need to make the  dispatch call outside of the `handleInputChange` function? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @clg123 you need to understand that object you pass to dispatch function appear as action in your reducer function. So when you write dispatch({ type: "YOUR_ACTION_TYPE", name: value }) you can get value in reducer as action.name; I don't quit understand what do you mean about state.itemname, but I'll try to update my answer, wait a couple of minutes

Comment: Hi again. I've got it working now thanks. Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: Sorry but I was wrong, it's still not working. The problem is basically I want to turn a string value (from the Json) into a variable name and then add that to the state. It's simple to do in Perl but not in Javascript apparently. I'm at a loss on how to proceed without just preloading all the form data rather than adding form elements dynamically. Even when I set the 'value' field of the new field to an existing value in the original `state` variable the element is not re-rendering. I really appreciate all the help and time you've given but maybe I need a different approach :)

Comment: Even when it calls the reducer and updates the state variable the element on the form doesn't update. I tested by using a pre-existing variable that I declare in `initialState` and I can see it's got updated by the `case 'UPDATE_FIELDS'` code but it still doesn't re-render. Once again thanks for your help and I'm going to try a different approach.

Comment: @clg123 hi ;) you definitly can generate form dynamicaly, but you need also update all the generated forms each time you rerender whole component. So instead of just generate new form once and write result to state and use this result in jsx you need to paste function directly in jsx, this will generate your forms and rerender them each time. Your function that generate new forms is some sort of just another child component and if you not rerender this component you will not see any results. Hope this help to guide you in right direction.

Comment: @clg123 if you can post updated codesandbox I'll try to help you